# Server setup option for rails with different ruby and rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting

I'm in the process of setting up my VPS (linode) to host a few rails websites. **What are some good options for setting up *one* server that will be hosting rails websites that are on different versions of rails and ruby.** For example

```
foo.com - ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0
bar.com - ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.3
```

I've seen only one [blog post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) (using passenger) regarding a setup like this but I'm interested in finding out what some other solutions look like. Or if this is a BAD idea and I should be using different VPS's for each I'd like to know othat too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example standalone Passenger or Unicorn instances per application, and reversproxy them via Apache or Nginx so it will respond on default port 80

Comment: Yah, this is about the best possible option today.  The guys at Phusion are in theory working on a new version of Passenger that will let you run multiple Ruby versions simultaneously (can already handle multiple Rails versions) but AFAIK it isn't ready for prime time yet.  Also, what's with the Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 bit?  I've seen lots of folks with 1.8.X and 1.9.X running simultaneously, but why can't you just fix up the 1.9.2 site to use 1.9.3?  They're not different at all in terms of features for Rails support...?

Comment: @Irongaze.com sorry, that was just an example but it was a BAD example :)

Comment: Per @astropanic, here's the link to doing the reverse proxy bit using Passenger (which rocks in my experience).  http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/